# What happens when Recycle Bin uses up its allocated space?

Tags: windows-7, windows, recycle-bin

My machine is set to store Recycle Bin for 1 GB. What happens when the Recycle Bin fills its space?

Does Windows **notify** you that it's full, or does it just automatically delete some files?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When the recycle bin's maximum size has been reached the oldest contents will be deleted to make room for the most recently deleted.

*[Source](http://www.pandorarecovery.com/knowledge_base/general/recycler.php) and more interesting facts about the Windows Recycle Bin.*

Comment: +1 The panda recovery article was interesting, thanks.

Comment: I think I'll just hide the Recycle Bin and forget about it. That way I'm not bothered by it and I can always recover my recently-deleted files. The performance hit isn't a big deal to me. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @DaveParillo,  @ Molly,  But the source is not from Microsoft so the info might be inaccurate and/or wouldn't work for future versions. Is there a document from an official Microsoft source?