# Is Windows 7 capable of Automatic Purging of Old in the Recycle Bin?

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens when the Recycle Bin uses up its allocated space?](https://superuser.com/questions/69284/what-happens-when-the-recycle-bin-uses-up-its-allocated-space)

Is Windows 7 capable of Purging the recycle bin Automatically, by removing the oldest deleted items?   **YES** see comments

Was this implemented in previous version of the windows operating system? **YES Xp had it**

Do you know of any controls they provide other than size to alter or change this behaviour?

Does the system inform the user prior to a purge? Or is this only tied to a cleaup operation?

I have one link, but little info there [Microsoft answers forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-7-automatically-deletes-files-from/961c8c8d-07da-4652-a734-f0e93bf39f0d)

Is it a problem for me? no. I just need to know what will happen. EX: say a users trashes hundreds of tiny items, then a few days later tosses out some much larger files. Then in hindsite wants one of the tiny files back.

**ADDED :** How blind of me, to have never noticed that XP would not allow a RecycleBin of greater than 4gig size, besides not being able to delete files over 4gig of size. I always had a Global 10% assigned, and just Assumed (duh) that it was 10% across the board.  With Win7 it really is 10% .

[Microsoft Resources](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/recycle_bin.mspx?mfr=true)
 Referance to XP **Items in the Recycle Bin remain there until you decide to permanently delete them from your computer.** These items still take up hard disk space and can be undeleted or restored back to their original location. **When it fills up, Windows automatically cleans** out enough space in the Recycle Bin to accommodate the most recently deleted files and folders.

---

Further adding to all the fun, the NTFS file system is claimed to "permenentaly" remove deleted files over 4gig , they were "not recoverable",  they were removed from the MFT itself?  Bringing up the question if any of that has changed in windows7 or 64bit.
[Google search for the >4gig recovery issue](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=files+over+4gig+are+not+recoverable&pbx=1&oq=files+over+4gig+are+not+recoverable&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=4649l11544l0l11716l35l29l0l4l4l0l218l4183l4.23.2l33l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=d6b4e92255e236a9&biw=1423&bih=929)

Comment: AFAIK Recycle bin follows a simple FIFO policy to determine which files are deleted when it goes over the quota

Comment: [What happens when the Recycle Bin uses up its allocated space?](http://superuser.com/questions/69284/what-happens-when-the-recycle-bin-uses-up-its-allocated-space)

Comment: You've got several questions here, so it's hard to give you an answer.

Comment: Well, techie's link has a link to more than all the information you want.

Comment: the pandora link? Here we do not recall that win95 win98 would do much of anything except fail on fill Informing the user to do something.  At the pandora link they lump 16 years of operating systems into 1 . Filling the trash for me is a rarity, having stuff not fit in the trash happens all the time. Now I want to know if it will do that in XP, and without asking.  I didnt recall that happening without me.

Comment: If my new system is going to put in the trash 4gig files now, it is going to change my trash patterns 100% . because now the 4+g files will go in??